# ASP.NET Codebehind limiting use of included login panel

Tags: asp.net

I have not touched ASP in almost ten years and I am not much of a programmer either so please excuse my vocabulary.
I work mainly UI so I am hoping someone here could help me solve what I think is a minor problem.

I have a site under construction which has a control panel for login/logout and it is in an include file on every page.

We currently have a "login page" which functions just fine but I want to take that and incorporate it into the control panel so the user could log in from any page.

Problem is that the .NET programmer wrote all of the login logic using code behind only on one single page.

Is there some way for me to work around this or to incorporate this vb code into every page so that the cpanel can function as it should?

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can move the login controls and codebehind to a user control. (.ascx) file, and then include it in your pages or your masterpages.

Comment: Ok I did a quick search on what an ascx is and it looks like exactly what I need.


Now the problem is, how do I see the code he wrote in his codebehind?

I see:
"<%@ Page CodeBehind="index.aspx.vb" Language="vb" AutoEventWireup="false" Inherits="siteControl.index" %>"

when I change that to:
"<%@ Page CodeBehind="index.aspx.vb" Language="vb" AutoEventWireup="false" Inherits="siteControl.login" %>

the login functions, so its in the inheriting that its getting its functionality.

Problem is, on the server I see no "index.asp.vb"

Comment: Not sure why its not registering my carriage returns above, sorry bout the readability.

Comment: When you 'publish' your website using Visual Studio, the source code doesn't get included on the location your publish to. The code is compiled and referenced to in the dll that is created.  You have to find the original source code that he wrote...maybe stored on his machine, source control server, or backup somewhere.

Comment: If I can get the original source code from him, am I forced to work with it in Visual Studio?

Comment: ASP.NET is very different from classic ASP...the server runs compiled code, not a script like ASP.
It's highly recommended you precompile the site with Visual Studio or the ASP.NET compiler tool before you put it on the server, but you don't have to. You could put the source code on the site and have the server compile it.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178466.aspx